# How load libraries to micro:bit v2?

Tags: python, micropython, bbc-microbit

I recently decided to write a library for the ds18b20 sensor for microbits, but I ran into a problem, I need other libraries for example datetime.

I tried to just install the library and run the code.

````
from microbit import *
from datetime import datetime


class DS18B20:
    def __init__(self, pin):
        self.pin = pin

    def sleep_us(self, us):
        lasttime = running_time() / 1000
        nowtime = running_time() / 1000
        while (nowtime - lasttime) < us:
            nowtime = running_time() / 1000

    def DS18B20Reset(self):
        self.pin.write_digital(0)
        self.sleep_us(750)
        self.pin.write_digital(1)
        self.sleep_us(15)

    def DS18B20WriteByte(self, data):
        _data = 0
        for i in range(8):
            _data = data & 0x01
            data >>= 1
            if _data:
                self.pin.write_digital(0)
                self.sleep_us(2)
                self.pin.write_digital(1)
                self.sleep_us(60)
            else:
                self.pin.write_digital(0)
                self.sleep_us(60)
                self.pin.write_digital(1)
                self.sleep_us(2)```
````

But, i got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'datetime'
```

Comment: Is it possible your Python is an antique?  The `datetime` module was not introduced until some time in the Python 2 era.  Since you're not using `datetime` here, why not just delete the line?

Comment: @TimRoberts this question is about the Micro:Bit, which runs [MIcropython](https://micropython.org/).

Comment: OK, then the answer is "the `datetime` module is not available," just as the message says.  You'll either have to do what you need with the `date` module, or see if you can install `datetime`.

Comment: I will use ```datetime``` soon. I will use it instead of ```running_time() / 1000``` as i need the exact time in microseconds

Answer (score 1):

There is no native `datetime` module available in Micropython. However, it looks like an implementation is available in the [`micropython-lib` repository](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/tree/master/python-stdlib/datetime).

You can install the `datetime.py` file on your Micro:Bit the same way you installed your own code and see if it meets your needs. The implementation is not going to be as full featured as the standard Python `datetime` module.

---

Looking at the code you've posted, other than your `import` statement you don't appear to actually be *using* the `datetime` module, so perhaps the easiest solution is just to remove the `import` statement.

Comment: I will use ```datetime``` soon. I will use it instead of ```running_time() / 1000``` as i need the exact time in microseconds.Also, is it possible to import other core python libraries?

Comment: It is not very correct to simply load the entire library, since it is large and if the code is large, then there is simply not enough space.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to install the library on the microbit itself without copying the file to it?

Comment: In general, copying a `.py` file to your device is the correct way to use it. The micro:bit is unfortunately very constrained in terms of storage, so if `datetime.py` is too large, you may want to figure out an alternative that doesn't require it. For what you're describing it doesn't sound like you need the `datetime` module at all -- you should just be able to use functions from the `time` module and simple math.

Comment: It is possible to build a custom version of micropython that has modules pre-compiled into it; this can save space but does require that you're able to successfully build micropython for your board. [This article](https://learn.adafruit.com/micropython-basics-loading-modules/frozen-modules) describes the process.